# Execute multiple bash commands on the output of find

Tags: bash, find, osx

I want to execute some commands using the find -exec option, but I'm not sure what' wrong with this code.  Currently, it's only processing the first find result, then getting stuck.  I'm using bash in OS X.

```
read -e DIRECTORY

find $DIRECTORY -type f -name '*.mov' -exec sh -c '
  file="$0"
  echo "Processing $file ..."
  modmovie -notrack "Timecode Track" $file -save-in-place
  read line </dev/tty
' {} \;
```

Comment: What's `read line </dev/tty` for exactly?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your command, it is just stuck at `read line </dev/tty` expecting input. If you type something and hit enter it will continue. What exactly is $line supposed to be?

Comment: @user21271 Generally speaking, always double-quote your variables to avoid word splitting, i.e. "$file" and "$DIRECTORY". Also, by convention, environment variables (PATH, EDITOR, SHELL, ...) and internal shell variables (BASH_VERSION, RANDOM, ...) are fully capitalized. All other variable names should be lowercase. Since variable names are case-sensitive, this convention avoids accidentally overriding environmental and internal variables.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this example and as others have said in the comments it's the `read line </dev/tty` that's causing it to wait for user input.

```
#!/bin/bash

find db -type f -name '*.jpg' -exec sh -c '
file="$0"
echo "hi"
echo "$file"
read line </dev/tty
' {} \;
```

#### My script's output

```
hi
db/db1440/gothamgardenxmas21440.jpg
     <---- I hit enter here
hi
db/db1440/unveiling11440.jpg
     <---- I hit enter here    
hi
db/db1440/astronomer21440.jpg
     <---- I hit enter here
...
```